# Dynamically have a ContextMenu for every ListViewItem in a ListView?

Tags: wpf

I am currently having a ContextMenu on a ListView with its view style set to "GridView". However, this gives me trouble because you are able to right-click the visual columns in the top of the ListView to get the context-menu to appear as well.

I only want the context menu to appear on all the items in the list, and I would hate to program a method to add a new context-menu for every list or so.

Is there a smart way of doing this? Maybe through a template of some sort? Which approach would be the best one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a style that will be applied to the items in the list view as opposed to the list view itself. Something like:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Send Email" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

For reference, I couldn't get it to work like this, as it kept resulting in the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu' to an object of type 'System.Object'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu' in markup file '<file>'.
```

Instead I had to use a static resource, which while having the exact same result, actually worked. Go figure.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListViewContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

<Application.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ListViewContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Play" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Application.Resources>
```